# Java interface and class organization convention within packages

Tags: java, package, conventions

I've seen the organization below, but was wondering if there are any established conventions or helpful advice for organizing classes and interfaces?

- [domain].[name]

  - foo

    - impl (contains classes with abstract and concrete implementations)
    - intf (contains interfaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule and your mileage may vary...

However, I recommend keeping related public interfaces and implementation code in the same package. In that way, the interfaces, enums, constants, factory classes, or whatever else needs to be publicly available is `public`, while implementation classes can be mostly or entirely `private` or only package visible. Putting implementation classes in a separate package will force some details to be `public` which would not otherwise have to be exposed.

Comment: I agree; there's a lot more flexibility when the entire module (or most of the module), including interfaces, is in the same package. I recently noticed a lot of high-profile libraries do this as well (Guava, Jersey, Apache xyz, etc...)